# How can I retrieve the data posted from this jQuery script in my application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, request

The script is as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myEl = document.getElementById('markAsRead');

    myEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var bloop = $('#markAsRead').val();
        alert(bloop);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/url/to/post',
            data: {"bloop": bloop},
            success: function(data) { alert('data: ' + data); },
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }, false);
</script>
```

I am posting this to a URL that wants to take the value of bloop and do something with it, but I am having trouble figuring out how to retrieve it to do so. Are there any obvious errors here? How can I access the value of bloop?

Comment: the "success" function in yours ajax request is your callback function.
What are been displayed in your alert message (alert('data: ' + data);) ?

Comment: are you using webApi as backend or MVC project . If with WEbApi/ MVC then you should have a route / controller method defined which takes string/ model object as parameter which you can read in server method .

Comment: let me know if my answer works if you need more help please ask .

Comment: @YashveerSingh I am using an MVC project, I will add this and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: @ruby_noobie your issues resolved ? or still having . ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like --- For MVC

```
 public IActionResult Post (string blob)
  {
      -- here you can get the value 
     return JsonResult ("Success");
   }
```